# Listen to Firebase DB changes in background of Android app

Tags: android

I'm creating my first Android app which is a Tinder clone just for learning purposes.

I'm trying to implement a way to constantly check for changes in the Firebase DB that would work in the background in any activity. e.g. when a user gets a new match and DB is updated, they get a popup notification(in app).

My thinking is maybe there some kind of listener that I need to run in a separate thread and put into every activity? Or just put a DB query in an infinite loop. I don't know what would be the best way.

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I'm kind of stuck and don't know how to move forward with this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the app to also pick up the Database changes when the app is closed or only while the user is using it?

Comment: Only when using the app. By 'in background' I mean user doesn't have to be in a specific activity and can be anywhere within the app, like in his profile settings or in chat activity and the popup will appear anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you said, you have to use a `ValueEventListener`. Try the code below:

```
DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Your path");

dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnaphsot dataSnaphsot){
        //There was a data change so make your pop-up notification.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){

    }
});
```

Using the `ValueEventListener` above, you will be notified everytime there is a change in your Firebase Database path, specified by `dbref`.

Then, in the `onDataChange` method, you can get the data that you need, and make the notification.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like exactly what was needed. I will try this ASAP and give feedback.

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly. I had some trouble with the paths, but figured it out eventually. 
For future reference:
DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matches").child(key);

And to get child item ID:
dataSnapshot.child("MatchID").getValue().toString()

Comment: You're welcome @robliv. If you don't mind could you please upvote my answer and mark it as accepted. Glad I was able to help.